# Unknown error acquiring position GeolocationPositionError code 2 - Firefox Linux Mint

Tags: reactjs, firefox, npm, linux-mint

Was trying to test geolocation function in my React project on `Firefox 74.0` on `Linux Mint 19.3`.

When trying to execute the following code:

```
 window.navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
        position => console.log(position),
        err => console.log(err)
    );
```

The following error was shown in the Firefox browser console:

```
GeolocationPositionError { code: 2, message: "Unknown error acquiring position" }
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

About a year ago Google changed its policies, so now it requires a valid API key when accessing their geolocation service.

If you type in your Firefox address bar:

```
about:config
```

and search the following:

```
geo.provider.network.url
```

you will see that its value is set to

```
https://www.googleapis.com/geolocation/v1/geolocate?key=%GOOGLE_LOCATION_SERVICE_API_KEY%
```

This tells us that you need a valid API key in place of `%GOOGLE_LOCATION_SERVICE_API_KEY%`

Until Mozilla solves this issue internally, the best solution is to change that value to:

```
https://location.services.mozilla.com/v1/geolocate?key=test
```

Note: This solution is best for testing. For production you can try ajax calls using either `fetch` or `axios` in React.